# Java generics with multiple parameters

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I have seen examples on the site that deal with generics with multiple parameters but none that work for my situation.

So here is the deal: I am trying to learn Java generics and have decided to create a simple binary array search utility function.  I am testing it out using custom objects and integers.  To get feedback on errors and warning I am using Eclipse.  Here is what I have:

```
public static int binarySearch(Comparable[] array, Comparable item, int start, int end) {
    if(end < start) {
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    if(item.compareTo(array[mid]) > 0) {
        return binarySearch(array, item, mid + 1, end);
    } else if(item.compareTo(array[mid]) < 0) {
        return binarySearch(array, item, start, mid - 1);
    } else {
        return mid;
    }
}
```

So obviously I get the warnings for Raw types saying the generics should be parameterized.  How can I do this correctly given that I have multiple parameters which both need to be the same type?

**SOLUTION**

Here is the working solution using generics with the correct parameter checks:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int binarySearch(T[] array, T item, int start, int end) {
    if(array.length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if(item == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if(start < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if(end < start) {
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    if(item.compareTo(array[mid]) > 0) {
        return binarySearch(array, item, mid + 1, end);
    } else if(item.compareTo(array[mid]) < 0) {
        return binarySearch(array, item, start, mid - 1);
    } else {
        return mid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just letting you know, this will fail if you pass in a zero-length or null array.

Comment: Yep, it is a trivial example - I am interested in the concept of multiple generics not the binary search. Thanks though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can specify function-specific generic parameter like so

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int binarySearch(T[] arr,T elem,int start,int end){
    //...
}
```

Comment: what does the <? super T> do for this?  Just curious is all - I see it often but never with an explanation.

Comment: it's some extra type safety and allows for more flexibility so you can pass an array of something whose superclass implements Comparable

Comment: @ratchetfreak Not exactly... It's saying that `T` can be a type of things that are comparable to some superclass of `T`, while forcing `arr` and `elm` to still be an array and an element of the same type.

Comment: @trutheality: What rathetfreak said is the usual case of when this happens. People usually write classes that are comparable to themselves. Thus if `T` is comparable to a superclass of `T`, that is usually because that superclass of `T` is comparable to itself, and `T` simply inherited it.

Answer (score 5):

This is the typical way to create generic functions:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int binarySearch(T[] array, T item, int start, int end) { ... }
```

For extra generality, `item` doesn't *have* to be of the same type the things in the array are, and things in the array don't *have* to be `Comparable` since you're not comparing them to anything, so

```
public static <T> int binarySearch(T[] array, Comparable<T> item, int start, int end) { ... }
```

gives some additional flexibility.

Comment: nice! i was wondering that too. for the context i think a stricter approach would be better, but that is great to know.  thanks.

Comment: great answer but just beat to the punch, i'll def 1 up your answer though, thanks a ton.